# I have query I want to know which script is faster , is any logic for that

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql script for pull data from database.

Please let me know which one is take less time.

```
--------1
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customers AS CUS 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Orders AS ORD 
ON CUS.CustomerID = ORD.CustomerID

--------2
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customers AS CUS 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Orders AS ORD 
ON ORD.CustomerID =CUS.CustomerID
```

Comment: This makes should not make any difference.  They should have exactly the same execution plan.

Comment: You could look at the execution plans yourself and see.

Answer (score 1):

**No script of the two is faster, they are completely the same.**

In your ON clause **you are only defining which columns are used to join two tables**. Sides of the equation have no impact whatsoever. You can write them as you choose :)